# Deploying JSF application on tomcat getting exception

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat6

When I'm deploying JSF2.0 application on tomcat6.0 I'm getting following exception:

```
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp
INFO: JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP c
ontainer.
```

I have included el-api2.2 and el-impl2.2 jar files in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib directory,as well as i have also included el-impl2.2.jar in my Project lib's folder.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have included el-api2.2 and el-impl2.2 jar files in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib directory*

Remove them. They don't belong there.

---

> *i have also included el-impl2.2.jar in my Project lib's folder.*

If I guess right the concrete functional requirement which you didn't tell anything about, then you actually just want to get EL 2.2 to work on Tomcat 6.0. In that case, you should drop the mentioned JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp and add the following entry to webapp's `web.xml`, assuming that you're indeed using Mojarra JSF implementation as hinted by the exception.

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```